# Java dependency management: IDE specific?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

The question above might be a tad misleading so I will have to expansiate a bit.

Recently I've been trying to pick up java to write a pretty straightforward rest API. I wanted to make it as lightweight as possible so settled on using the java spark framework.

The official docs explain how to use spark with maven but I decided to go with Gradle since it looks to be the better alternative.

After about 6 hours I was unable to get the sample code from the spark docs to work. When trying to compile my project the spark library was somehow not being recognized. Autocopletion showed all the classes of the spark framework but the code just refused to compile for some reason.

A friend later heled me get a project going with maven. There was an issue there as well. The dependencies in the spark framework's pom file were not getting installed for some reason. I had to install them manually.

Later I read some posts on how intellij(my IDE) doesn't play well with Gradle. I was a bit confused as I am not sure why an IDE should have an influence over a dependentcy manager.

I primarily use nodejs and dependency management is pretty straightforward. Of course once in awhile an issue or two will pop up but fixing it will be trivial.

So I just want to know where is the issue coming from? Is it possible that I did not configure something properly? Is there something about the spark framework that doesn't make it play well with Gradle? Do I need to modify or export a library in some way to be supported by maven/Gradle? Can my IDE interfer with my dependency manager in some way?

I would really appreciate it if someone could share some light on the questions above as I was unable to find any useful info on this yet.

**UPDATE:** All config files and source below:

**Main.java**

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
group 'sparking'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'sparking07'
```

**Error stack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Request
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Request
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.Request
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**UPDATE:** Dependency screeshot:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not play well"? What problems did you run into? What did you try?

Comment: I read some post about how a user's project refused to use his local copy of Gradle and continuously tried to download another version

Comment: Another in which the Gradle settings file was not being picked up by a project

Comment: As I mentioned I am just starting out. But I did not expect to run in into issues so quick. All I did was create a new project in intellij. Provided a local copy of Gradle. A simple hello world compiled and ran properly. I then included the spark library. Included the sample test code. When I tried to build I got an error that class definitions were missing.

Comment: Please, be specific and precise. Post your build file, post your code, post your gradle version, post the command you executed, and post the output you got. Saying basically "I tried something, and it didn't work" makes it impossible for us to help. If it builds with gradle (on the command line), but doesn't in IntelliJ, then post your IntelliJ version, tell how you created the project in IntelliJ, tell what you tried doing in IntelliJ, and what happened, precisely. Withe the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Builds perfectly fine both with gradle (3.5) on command line, and after opening the project in IntelliJ (2017.1.3), with Cmd-F9. You still haven't posted what you're doing, and what happens.

Comment: I outlined the steps above. IntelliJ. New project. Using gradle. Provided my local gradle(ver 3.5). donwloaded spark by including it in mybuild.gradle file. Tried building and got an error. Error in question above

Comment: What you posted is a runtime exception. It can't happen when building. Close your project. Choose File - Open, choose the build.gradle file. Once imported, make sure, in File - Project structure, that the language level and JDK are correct (1.8.x, 8). Hit Cmd-F9 (or Ctrl-F9 on Windows/Linux) to build. Tell what happens. To run, right-click on Main, and select "Run Main.main". If you still have a problem, expand the External Libraries node in the explorer, and post an image of the IDE frame.

Comment: The integration is fine, since everythig is resolved correctly, and the build passes. I have no idea how you get this exception when running the Main class. It doesn't happen here. Try inspecting the jar file to see if it's there. Or deleting the cache under the .gradle directory in your home dir to force gradle to redownload teh dependencies.

Comment: ok. I will try that then. Thanks for your help.